# Работа COUNT в MySQL

Tags: mysql, count

Имеется таблица юзеров вида id (первичный ключ), name, lastname и таблица лайков вида from_user, to_user. Больше никаких индексов нет.

```
SELECT users.user_id AS ID,
CONCAT(users.user_name, ' ', users.user_lastname) AS 'User',
COUNT(DISTINCT l2.from_user) AS 'Likes received',
COUNT(DISTINCT l1.to_user) AS 'Likes delivered' FROM users
INNER JOIN likes AS l1 ON users.user_id = l1.from_user
INNER JOIN likes AS l2 ON users.user_id = l2.to_user
WHERE users.user_id = 3;
```

Вопрос. Почему не работает CONCAT, если выборка даст отсутствие результатов. Например, один пользователь не поставил никому лайк, а я по нему делаю выборку, то количество отправленных соответственно 0 и тогда COUNT ломается. Что можно сделать? В таблице likes оба поля с атрибутом UNIQUE, чтобы исключить возможность дважды лайкнуть другого юзера.
Скрипты:

```
CREATE TABLE users ( user_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, user_name varchar(45) NOT NULL, user_lastname varchar(45) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (user_id) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
CREATE TABLE likes ( from_user int NOT NULL, to_user int NOT NULL, UNIQUE KEY from_user_UNIQUE (to_user,from_user) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
INSERT INTO social_network.users (user_name, user_lastname) VALUES ('name1', 'lastname1'), ('name2', 'lastname2'), ('name3', 'lastname3'), ('name4', 'lastname4'), ('name5', 'lastname5');
INSERT INTO social_network.likes (from_user, to_user) VALUES ('2', '1'), ('4', '1'), ('1', '2'), ('4', '2'), ('1', '3'), ('2', '3'), ('3', '4');
```

Comment: Добавьте скрипты CREATE TABLE для обеих таблиц, и cкрипты INSERT INTO с образцами данных(3-5 записей), один из которых показывает нормальный результат, а второй -  что означает "COUNT ломается". Не используемые в запросе поля и все индексы (кроме PK и FK между этими таблицами) можно смело поскипать.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `users` (
   `user_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `user_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
   `user_lastname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

Comment: CREATE TABLE `likes` (
   `from_user` int NOT NULL,
   `to_user` int NOT NULL,
   UNIQUE KEY `from_user_UNIQUE` (`to_user`,`from_user`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

Comment: Пишите не в комментарии, а в теле вопроса. С оформлением как положено

Comment: INSERT INTO `social_network`.`users` (`user_name`, `user_lastname`) VALUES ('name1', 'lastname1'), ('name2', 'lastname2'), ('name3', 'lastname3'), ('name4', 'lastname4'), ('name1', 'lastname1');

Comment: INSERT INTO `social_network`.`likes` (`from_user`, `to_user`) VALUES ('2', '1'), ('4', '1'), ('1', '2'), ('4', '2'), ('1', '3'), ('2', '3'), ('3', '4');

Comment: Забыл сказать, что в таблице likes оба поля с атрибутом UNIQUE, чтобы исключить возможность дважды лайкнуть другого юзера

Comment: Пожалуйста, найдите под текстом вопроса ссылку "править". Нажмите её и добавьте в текст вопроса скрипты, корректно отформатированные. А комментарии с этой лапшой - удалите.